# Breakpoints dont work Remote debugging Play/Activator

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, remote-debugging, typesafe-activator

I just started with the Play Framework but to learn these kind of things it is amazingly convenient to be able to use breakpoints.

Now I figured quickly that when I run 'activator -jvm-debug 9888' I can connect my Intellij CE 14 to its debugger. That seems to work, console gets nicely printed on the webui 'standard out' but not in my Intellij even when it says it connected.:

'Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:9888', transport: 'socket''

But that is truly about it, no console messages are show or breakpoints get hit inside intellij

Anyone had the same problem before and knows how to solve it? (Googling didn't find me the answer!)

Greets

Comment: PS I run on windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your build.sbt try to add this line (with a capital T!):

```
fork in Test := false
```

For info see http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Forking.html

Comment: I indeed figured it out that it was that setting! Anyway, you will get the points ;)